# Type mismatch error when copying cells from another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having a type mismatch error when I try to copy a cell from a workbook. Any idea as to what is wrong here ?

```
 Workbooks(inv).Sheets(sheetname).Cells(r.Row, price.Column).Copy
```

inv is a workbook,
sheetname is a string,
r is a range containing a single cell,
price is a range containing a single cell. The content of the cell I'm trying to copy is a numeric value.

Comment: Can you update your question with the code that assigns the variables

Comment: When you get the error and enter Debug mode, hover over each of the vars in that code line. What are the values?

Answer (score 4):

If `inv` is a workbook object then:

```
inv.Sheets(sheetname).Cells(r.Row, price.Column).Copy
```

Your code as written would work if `inv` was a String